# How to find 'Text' after node?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

URL= ['https://makemyhomevn.com/collections/ghe-an-cafe/products/ghe-go-tron']

driver.get(URL)
sleep(1)
des = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="product-item-description"]//strong/following sibling::text()[1]')
print(des)
```

I expect my result as 'Gỗ tự nhiên', I have tried many ways but couldn't get the text after 'Chất liệu:'.
[image]

Comment: Are you sharing the right web page ? I see this `Gỗ MFC phủ Mellamine, Gỗ MDF phủ Mellamine` instead of `Gỗ tự nhiên'`

Comment: Please see below my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the **entire span text** using `.get_attribute('innerText')` and then use the `split function from Python` like below:

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://makemyhomevn.com/collections/ghe-an-cafe/products/ghe-go-tron")
time.sleep(1)
entire_span = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Chất liệu:']/..")))
entire_span_splitted = entire_span.get_attribute('innerText').split(":")
#print(entire_span_splitted[0])
print(entire_span_splitted[1])
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
 Gỗ tự nhiên.
```